# jquery.Countdown - changing background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, countdown

I have a issue with this script -

```
  var date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 60 * 1000);

  $('#clock').countdown(date)
  .on('update.countdown', function(event) {

   var format = '%M:%S';

    if(date < 30) {

      $( "#countcon" ).addClass( 'bg-teal-800' );
    }

   $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
   })
   .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
   $(this).html('This offer has expired!')
     $( "#countcon" ).removeClass( 'bg-teal-800' );
     $( "#countcon" ).addClass( 'bg-pink-800' );
   });
```

I want **If date < 30 seconds** change the background color of a DIV (countcoun) but Its didn't Works right.

at the end the changing background color (teal to pink) it's working ok..

I tried - **if(event.offset.seconds < 30)**, but no response too.. (with this the countdown starts with TEAL Background color.

Answer (score 1):

You're asigning a Data Object to the variable date in this line:

```
var date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 60 * 1000);
```

Try adding the following line right after your asignment:

```
alert(data);
```

What this then displays is something like:

```
Fri Jul 22 2016 11:59:14 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

which means that you cannot possibly compare all that to `30` and execute a command if it's true as it never will. I guess you want to check for whether the current 'second' of your timer is below then 30. If so, you'll have to change your if-statement to:

```
if(event.strftime('%S') < 30){}
```

What `event.strftime('%S')` is doing is to return the current time of your countdown formatted to only seconds such as:

```
19
```

This can then be compared to the int `30` in the if-statement. To check for a counter-time in years, month, days, hours, minutes... one has to change the time-formatting in the if-statement, as **'%S' stands for seconds**. Refer to the Countdown [formatting-documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#formatter).

Comment: first of all tks a lot for your time and help @kevin-katze. I insert the code as you said, but the alert brings to me the seconds from current time - and not for the countdown.. The countdown starts with 1:00

Comment: I edited my answer. Know the if-statement should work as expected. Please check for further issues.

Comment: YES! great and simple solution! I tried a lot of alternatives, but none Works.. tks a lot!!!

Comment: hi @kevin-katzke I made a better test here and the solution Works with 0:30 countdown, but dont work with more time.. like 10:00.. I'm testing here..

Comment: Im testing here.. its Works with any countdown until 0:59. If I put minute, its brokes the code.. and stop working..

Comment: hi! I got it! Usign the same logic -  but I dont know why with if(event.strftime('%M') = 0) dont work.. (code are broke.. the coutdonwn stops). but with if(event.strftime('%M') < 1) I got it!  If you update your answer with this information , I will check you as right.. tks a lot!!

Comment: Obviously the code breaks if  you want to check for any time above 0:59 as for now we are formatting the time to seconds. If you want to check if the time is blow 10 minutes this cannot possibly work. 

You then need to change to time-format in the if-statement so that it outputs minutes. Refer to the [format documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#formatter). Something like if(event.strftime('%M') < 10){} should work.

Comment: if(event.strftime('%M') = 0) is an asignment and not a comparsion ([JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp))! You need to change this to if(event.strftime('%M') == 0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118025/discussion-between-kevin-katzke-and-daniel).